# d3.js selection's enter() section gets called only once

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm building a map on which bubbles represent tweets. Every once in a while I ask if there are new tweets from server, using `d3.json` and it returns me locations of new tweets.

I bind this array, containing only new locations using `selectAll.()data()` and expect them to be in the `enter()`section on each new request with new data. But I only get there once, event though the data join seems to work.

I add everyting on the svg group that I've created like this:

```
bubbleGroup = svg.append("g").attr("class", "bubble");
```

Then I add the circles the following way:

```
  var circlesSelection = bubbleGroup.selectAll("circle")
  .data(tweets, function (tweet) {
  console.log("We have new data:");
  console.log(tweet);
  return tweet;
  });

  circlesSelection.enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("transform", function(tweet) {
  console.log("Gets called only once");

  return "translate(" + tweet["location"] + ")";})
  .attr("r", 5);
```

So, while the first log displayed all the time, with new data from array, the second one only once.

Is there some fundamental misunderstanding of d3.js framework here, or just some minor bug of mine?

The page that proves this behavior is the following:[example](http://128.199.62.25/static/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're logging in two completely different contexts -- first in the key function of the data join and then in the enter selection. The first log will be called at least once per element in the data array as the purpose of that function is to return a key that tells D3 how to match data and DOM elements. The second will be called once for every new data element (i.e. it couldn't be matched to an existing DOM element).

If not all of the elements that you expect show up in the enter selection, you need to adjust your key function -- in particular, I would use `tweet.tid` as the key in your case.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but doesn't every element that was once logged in the data join has to be logged at least once in the enter selection with this code? And what could be the possible adjustment of the key function? Array of data is basically a dictionary, if that's important.

Comment: Not if there are `circle` elements that match the data in the DOM already, which is likely to be the case if I interpret your code correctly as you're retrieving the 10 latest tweets regardless of whether you've seen them before. I would use the ID of the tweet, i.e. `return tweet.tid` in the key function.

Comment: That would really sound like a right answer, and I'll try this one, but the thing is that if this was the case, there should be some objects that would be different and that would result in the entering this section, but that never happens except the very first time.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. If you have new tweets (i.e. with a new tid) then yes, these should appear in the enter selection.

Comment: But they don't, only the tweets that are in the first selection appear there, and none of the following ones.

Comment: Did you check the data and that everything is matched correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by matching, but, as I said, new elements are logged in the data() join, and just after that they don't get displayed in the enter() selection. Could it be because of that the `tweets` is always array of 10 elements? Does the new selection has to be bigger for the update() method to get called?

Comment: No, you just need to supply a suitable key function. Have you tried using `tweet.tid` as a key?

Comment: Thanks, just tried it and it started to work — you can updated the answer with this notice and see the result at the same page: http://128.199.62.25/static/index.html